# Receiving an error when trying to backup bitlocker key to Azure AD with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, bitlocker

We are trying to create a script within our environment to upload bitlocker keys to Azure AD using powershell and BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector

But we receive an error message on all PCs we have tried so far, error message:

```
BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector : JSON value not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x83750009)
At line:1 char:1
+ BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive -KeyPr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector
```

I have tried the following and multiple other scripts:

```
BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive -KeyProtectorId ((Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive ).KeyProtector | where {$_.KeyProtectorType -eq "RecoveryPassword" }).KeyProtectorId
```

When checking with (Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive ).KeyProtector it does output a KeyRrotectorID and RecoveryPassword.

Do anyone have any idea what's going on, or why it's not working?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to backup bit locker key to Azure AD with PowerShell**

You can use below **PowerShell** script to backup **Bit locker key** to **Azure AD** with **PowerShell**.

```
Connect-AzureAD

$BitlockerVol = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive
        $BPID=""
        foreach($BP in $BitlockerVol.KeyProtector){
            if($BP.KeyProtectorType -eq "RecoveryPassword"){
                $BPID=$BP.KeyProtectorId
                break;
            }
        }
       BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "$($env:SystemDrive)" -KeyProtectorId ((Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive ).KeyProtector | where {$_.KeyProtectorType -eq "RecoveryPassword" }).KeyProtectorId
```

Once ran the above **PowerShell** code, it got executed successfully.

[image]

To check the **Bit locker Keys** in **Azure AD**,

**Go to Azure Active Directory > Devices > All devices >Search your Device >BitLocker keys (Preview) > Show Recovery Key.**

[image]